# Retrieve Model type in Rails Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does a helper class in Rails 5 (for example `UserHelper`) have access to the model type it is related to (`User`)?

I have some shared logic `AddFilter` that requires the model type to work propery. I now enforce a method `filter_for` to specify which model is used:

```
module AddFilter
  def filter_for
    raise "filter_for not implemented"
  end

  #...other code
end
```

Currently I include that logic in many of my helpers:

```rb
module UserHelper
  include AddFilter

  def filter_for
    User
  end
end
```

It is possible to retrieve the model type in the `AddFilter` directly?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently since helpers are included in controllers, a feature from controllers can be used:

```rb
# add_filter.rb
def filter_for
    controller_path.classify.constantize
end
```

This [retrieves the controller path](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/controller_path), [classifies the name](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/classify), then [tries to find the constant](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/constantize) specified.

Still feels rather hacky, better solutions appreciated!

Comment: This is excellent but I will suggest this method to be defined in `ApplicationHelper`